# please select android sdk

Tags: android, build, sdk

Problem description:

- I clone a project from github, then `sync`, successful. But the module `sample` in configuration menu is error, as below
  [image]
- I open a java file and find that Android SDK api cannot resolved, and there is no `Android API Library`  in `External Libraries` of project root directory.
- I check `Project Structure`, my configuration is all right
  [image]
  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I find this project need `Android Plugin Version 3.1.4` by check `Project Structure` or root project file `build.gradle`, as below:

```
buildscript {

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }

}
```

that mean `Android Studio` should be `3.1.4` or higher. But my `Android Studio` is `3.1.3`. Then I update my `Android Studio` to `3.1.4` and this problem disappear

Answer (score 1):

If you use Android studio 3.1.4, please use this solution.

Solution:

- File — > Invalidate Caches — > Invalidate
- File — > Close Project.
- Remove the project from the AS project selector window.
- Quit from
  Android Studio Start Android Studio and open project again

Base on this link: https://android.jlelse.eu/android-studio-3-1-how-to-fix-it-b49f72eb054f